# Neo4j - Which federal state has members in the most committees?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and am learning the basics. So far I've managed to get this together:

```
MATCH (l:Legislator)-[:REPRESENTS]->(s:State)
MATCH (l)-[:SERVES_ON]->(c:Committee)
WITH s.code as states, count(c) as committees
return states, committees
order by committees DESC
```

This query gives me the following output:

```
s.code   committees
"CA"     90
"TX"     70
"NY"     51
"FL"     43
"PA"     36
"IL"     35
...      ...
```

If I understand correctly the output tells me how many relationships there are between all `Legislator` and all `Committee` nodes in every `State`

How would I need to change the query so that I get the number of unique committees the members of each state are in?

Something that would output:

```
s.code   committees
"NY"     29
"TX"     27
"CA"     25
...      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using distinct:

```
MATCH (l:Legislator)-[:REPRESENTS]->(s:State) 
MATCH (l)-[:SERVES_ON]->(c:Committee)
WITH s.code as states, count(distinct c) as committees
return states, committees
order by committees DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed. I didn't know you could use distinct like that. I tried using distinct in return but that didn't change the output.